# IIS sends connection reset on 2 out of 4 sites

Tags: security, iis

I have 4 websites on an IIS server (hosted on windows 2016)
2 websites works as expected,
for 2 websites the request doesn't reach IIS at all - and I get connection RESET.

running Wireshark I've noticed that the working websites gets client hello with TLSv1.2
and the non working websites gets client hello with TLSv1 that ends up with RST.

Not sure why it happens, or how to debug / solve this.

[image: Wireshark image]

same server - another website:

[image: wireshark good session]

Comment: Review SSL/TLS settings using tools like IIS Crypto https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/ It is best practice to disable TLS 1.0 and 1.1 now, so I don't think resetting TLS 1.0 connections is a problem.

Comment: TLS Settings are global for the whole server, so it either affects all sites or none. I would compare the certificates of the working and not-working sites, are there still SHA-1 hashes used?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - the certificate for that site was either wrong (for one) or none set (for the other).
For some reason - that caused the tls1.0 handshake and connection reset (why ?)